# Jquery input get value of self and sibling inputs on event

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the value of an input (radio button) when it is clicked on and the value of its siblings. Using Jquery I can get the value of its siblings with the code below, but can't think of how to include the value of the selected element itself.

```
options = $(button).siblings('input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
      return this.value;
    }).get();
```

Comment: Your question is not completely clear to me - but i guess the jquery attribute selectors will help you: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can traverse to parent element and then find checked elements in it this will also ensure that it is not considering current checkbox when it is unchecked:

```
$(button).parent().find('input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
  return this.value;
}).get();
```

Comment: Bingo! Simple solution I should have seen myself.  Now I am feeling kind of stupid.

Comment: @skribe: glad it helps :)